# Why am I getting a wrongly formed request with this angularjs form?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following table:

```
<uib-accordion>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Roles" is-open="true">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Role Name</th>
                <th>Access for</th>
                <th>Access to</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="role in ctrl.app.roles.base track by $index">
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputRoleName" name="inputID" ng-model="role.id" placeholder="Enter mame of role" ng-minlength='3' ng-maxlength='100' required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputResource1" name="inputRes1" ng-model="role.res1" placeholder="Enter name of first resource" ng-minlength='3' ng-maxlength='100' required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputResource2" name="inputRes2" ng-model="role.res2" placeholder="Enter name of second resource" ng-minlength='3' ng-maxlength='100' required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAction" name="inputAc" ng-model="role.action" placeholder="Enter action required" ng-minlength='3' ng-maxlength='100' required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="cbtn cbtn-plus" ng-click="ctrl.AddRole('base')">+</button>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

It basically is a table, with a '+' button situated at the bottom of the table, and whenever you click it, 4 text boxes will appear to fill the values. Now, I have written the following controller function for this:

```
function AddRole(section) {
    if (!self.app.roles) self.app.roles = {};
    if (!self.app.roles[section]) self.app.roles[section] = [];
    self.app.roles[section].push({actions: []});
}
```

However, when I see the JSON request being formed, there is something going wrong with this. Because, in the JSON request, no matter what value I fill inside the text boxes, I see this:

```
"roles":{"base":[{"actions":[]}]}
```

Where am I going wrong in this?
Thanks!

Comment: Create a demo in plunker that reproduces issue. What are you expecting as results?

Comment: All your ng-models use `role.xxx`. I don't see this `role` variable defined anywhere. In particular, the ng-repeat doesn't define it. It defines a variable named `roles`.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes, that was a typo on my part. Corrected it in the code but still the same problem persists. Basically, the data I enter in the boxes doesn't get inserted.

Comment: It worked. The problem basically was, in function, AddRole, `actions` was colliding with a variable in one other controller function. Also, I have a doubt, is it mandatory to keep the variable name (either of `id` or `res1` or `res2` or `action`?) Otherwise if I keep it something else, an empty variable is automatically inserted in the JSON request formed?